# flutter pub get Wrong full snapshot version

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter pub get
Wrong full snapshot version, expected '36b0375d284ee2af0d0fffc6e6e48fde' found '90b56a561f70cd55e972cb49b79b3d8b'
exit code 255

Tried to search the code but to no avail.
How can I get this error solve Geniuses.